# Can't dismiss keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I can't figure out how to dissmis keyboard when Done or something outside textfield is touched. Here is what I try

myController.h

```
@interface myController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{
    secondViewController *secondView;
}
```

myController.m

```
-(void)loadView
{
    .....
    textFieldRounded.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textFieldRounded.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    textFieldRounded.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    textFieldRounded.placeholder = @"<enter text>";  
    textFieldRounded.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
    textFieldRounded.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;    
    textFieldRounded.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;  
    textFieldRounded.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  
    textFieldRounded.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;    
    [textFieldRounded.delegate = self;        
    [self.view addSubview:textFieldRounded];

    ....
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make keyboard hidden by tap outside textfield, you can use gesture recognizer as shown below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  // don't forget to assign textField delegate, after textField is created
  textFieldRounded.delegate = self;

  //...
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];
  tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
  [tapRecognizer release]
}

- (void)singleTap:(id)sender
{
  // if you have multiple text fields use this line:
  [self.view endEditing:NO];
}

// remove resigning call from textField delegate
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}

// on Done/Return button handling use this
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
```

To capture when you touch outside of the textfield

Comment: I have set NSLog in textFieldShouldEndEditing and as far I see NSLog is not executed.

Comment: I changed my first answer, try that one

Comment: Just use that one instead of textFieldShouldEndEditing, and do the same in the same place

Comment: Well now it works if I touch Done button, but not when outside of the textfield is touched.